# Is it possible to use the same register as a memory pointer and data in the same instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

For example, in the following instruction:

```
MOV [BX], BH
```

The register BH is part of the register BX.

Comment: Yes, this is allowed.

Comment: Are there any risks or things I should be careful about when using this command?
By the way, I ask this question because in my textbook it was written that it is forbidden, which seemed illogical to me, so I wanted to verify if they were wrong.

Comment: Its usefulness is somewhat limited, since the address determines the value you can store at that address (and vice versa).

Comment: @Deftera There are no risks at all.  The instruction (there are no commands in assembly) does exactly what it says.

Comment: There is nothing to be unexpected by this instruction.  It can be encoded, and the processor will happily execute that.  Since we know that `bx` holds an address, then `bh` is the upper 8-bits of that address.  For example if `bx` holds 0x1234 then this instruction will store the byte 0x12 at the address 0x1234. (assuming intel syntax)  If it was `mov [bx],bx` then it would store the word 0x1234 at address 0x1234 (0x34 at 0x1234 and 0x12 at 0x1235).

Comment: The other way around is more useful: `MOV BH, [BX]` could be nice if you don't need the address for anything further, and then you can use BH for the value instead.  Either way, you can think if you like that the "input" is copied into some temporary location while the instruction executes, so that it isn't affected by overwriting the register.

Comment: With some architectures other than x86 there are caveats.  For instance, with the writeback pre/post indexing loads and stores on ARM64, you may not do `LDR X0, [X0], 8` which would otherwise add 8 to X0 after the load was done.  But on x86 it's perfectly safe.  What did your textbook actually say?  It's possible you understood something different from what they meant.

Comment: The textbook is written in Hebrew but can be translated directly into:
"The instruction `MOV [BX], BH` is invalid because the BH register is part of the BX register."

Comment: Ok, that's a clear enough statement that it's definitely wrong, not something you're misinterpreting.  (Unless they possibly mean "invalid" as part of implementing something else, where the choice of BH here would imply choosing BH in other instructions, in ways that would overwrite part of your pointer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There's no problem with this**, and not even any reason to think it might be disallowed.  (Except for your textbook which apparently [incorrectly claims it's invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65742113/is-it-possible-to-use-the-same-register-as-a-memory-pointer-and-data-in-the-same#comment116236972_65742113)).  A store just reads the address register(s) and the data register, and writes into memory at that address.
Reading registers in modern CPUs is typically done with multi-ported register files that allow two or more independent reads to be done in the same clock cycle.  Register files are built out of SRAM so there's zero problem reading the same set of cells twice at the same time.

`mov bx, bh` would of course not be legal because the registers have different width, not because one overlaps.  `mov cx, bh` is just as illegal.  (But 386 `movzx ebx,bh` is fine.)

In fact it's common for linked-list reading loops to contain an instruction like `mov bx, [bx]` or equivalent with other registers.  (Iterating over a linked list is called "pointer chasing".)  It's also common to simply replace a pointer you don't need anymore with some data.

It's less common to store (part of) a pointer to the pointed-to location, but the CPU doesn't care whether it's useful.

---

There are a few ISAs where some instructions have restrictions on using the same register, e.g. older ARM has a problem when a multiply uses the same register for output as input.  But simple instructions like load or store aren't weird like that.

Except with addressing modes that update the pointer register as well as loading into a different register.  Nate suggested `LDR X0, [X0], 8` as an example of something that's not allowed.  `ldr x1, [x0], 8` does `x1 = mem[x0] ; x0+=8` ([post-indexed](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/learn-the-architecture/aarch64-instruction-set-architecture/loads-and-stores-addressing)), and is not allowed with x1 = x0.

x86 doesn't have any pre/post-indexed explicit addressing modes, but x86 does have push/pop which implicitly use [E/R]SP as the address and take one explicit data operand.  The manual documents exactly what happens for [`push sp`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push) and [`pop sp`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pop).  (pop sp = `mov sp, [sp]`, if that was encodeable.)

**In general, explicitly documented otherwise for that instruction, you can assume that the same register (or overlapping partial registers) is/are valid choices for the operands and/or addresses.**

**In the x86 case, there aren't any disallowed same-register operands for any instruction I can think of.**  If it's encodeable, it will have some well-defined behaviour.  There are some combos that are unlikely to be *useful*, like `div dx` which is guaranteed to raise a `#DE` exception from dividing DX:AX by DX, such that the result can never fit in AX.

Comment: Your answer starts with "No, there's no problem" but from the question (at least how it is now) it seems that it should rather read "Yes, there's no problem".